# What attack requests "wp-admin" URLs without login cookies?

Tags: wordpress

Looking through my Apache log files ("combined" log file record format), I see a large number of requests for URLs ending in "wp-admin". This is pretty weird, as my server doesn't run WordPress. I also have a 404 document that's a PHP program that records $_REQUEST, $_SERVER, $_COOKIE and $_FILES. I have apparently deleted a bunch of that output, but in what I have retained, none of the requests for "wp-admin" URLs have WordPress login cookies.

As near as I can tell, this is some new attack, I don't have record of it from last summer.

What's going on here? A real WordPress installation just redirects to the WordPress login. An unconfigured WordPress just gives an error message.  What on earth can you figure out from this information?

**UPDATE**: add extra information requested by an answerer. This is from a "typical" probe.

Complete requested URL: http://stratigery.com/wp-admin/

No cookies, not even the "wordpress_test_cookie" that WordPress' wp-login.php sends with its initial login screen HTML, HTTP GET, no GET parameters. No User-Agent string. Connection: Close.

`p0f` says it comes from "Linux 2.6 (newer, 10) (possibly Ubuntu 11.04)".

In other such requests, the URL may end in `/blog/wp-admin/`, `/wordpress/wp-admin/` or `/wp/wp-admin/`. and in a very few cases, `/wordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/`. Every such request shares the lack of cookies, no User-Agent string, GET method, and no GET parameters on the URL, along with "Connection: Close". I'd have to do some time consuming work to get a sender TCP port number range, and a better collection of what `p0f` thinks that the sending OS is.

Comment: Maybe it is just trying to create a list of valid wordpress sites, so that it may target them specifically later. If it 404s, then it moves on and tries another domain. Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the complete requested URL (and any post or get vars) it is impossible to say for sure.

There are numerous things they could be trying. It could as Gray suggests someone carrying scans to ascertain which domains are running wordpress (however getting this information from Google would be a much easier prospect).

Another possibility is that someone has misidentified your domain as running wordpress (has it ever used wordpress?). They could be scanning your site using something like wpscan. If wpscan is being used I would expect many other requests around the same time looking for other files (for example the plugins folder).

As you suggest they could also be looking for a specific vulnerability. However without knowing what scripts they are trying to reach and if there are any post or get vars then it wouldn't be possible for us to ascertain this.

Comment: see updated question for extra information. My site has only ever run a honey pot that resembles WordPress. The requests appear isolated - not preceded by requests for wp-login.php, or followed by requests for anything else.

Comment: Going by your update it looks like they are simply scanning for wordpress blogs that they can come back too later to try to compromise.